# Is it ok for the boss to rebuke an employee in front of a client?

Tags: professionalism, management, behavior

I am in the e-commerce Industry and the other day we had a meeting with an unsatisfied client. During the meeting, the client mentioned that a colleague of mine (present in the room) was not very cooperative, which was somewhat true.

At that point, our boss started to rebuke him in front of the client. My colleague was, of course, silent and defenseless, as he probably should be.

Is it ok for the boss to behave in such a manner in front of a client?

Personally, I felt it was wrong because it surely affects negatively to the teams morale, and respectively, it affects the image of the team to the clients eyes since the boss, in a way, openly confirms the clients claim of the team's weakness.

But that is from my perspective as an employee, so I suppose I am not that objective.

Comment: Just because it has a negative effect on morale does not mean it is wrong.    With out more specifics on how the rebuke was handled it is hard to judge anyway.  But you are asking for an opinion on your bosses actions, which is off topic on this SE.

Comment: @Chad I'm sorry but I'm new here, why exactly is this off topic?

Comment: Judging your bosses actions are purely opinion responses.  It is similar to asking what did you think of a movie.  This is a Q&A site not a forum.  We seek questions that have definitive answers, like how to do something, or explaining why.  We could probably guess at why your boss did that but I am sure you get it too.  We just can not judge your boss for his actions it doesnt help anyone.

Comment: To give you an example, an answerable question could be "Should a manager rebuke a employee in front of a client that has complained about that employee?"

Comment: @Chad I still don't get it, if I was the boss and I was asking if it was right to handle the situation like this, what difference would it make?

Comment: @JJChivers I'm sorry but I believe that even if the question is rephrased the possible answers would be the same.

Comment: We don't have enough info to have valid opinions.

Comment: In general terms praise should be given in public and reprimand in private.    What is OK in this situation is going to be nuanced based on a lot of external factors that we don't have.  Risk of lost business versus employee morale is going to be a tricky thing.

Comment: I think the boss is being really unprofessional .Even if you deserved it what the boss did was wrong and shows that He/She is not suitable to be a boss no matter how good subject matter knowledge is .I saw this in the health proffession in CHCH NZ in a private hospital chain of all places .I thought that such people should know better.

Comment: Going off of Joe's did you manager pull your colleague aside after and apologise as your manager thought the client wanted to see the reprimand.  Or was it a "Just to be clear, We value this client as a customer and I expect that you will give their requests priority in the future."  That is not really a rebuke so much as a show of support of the clients requests.  It is considerably different form "You are completely worthless and I do not know why you are on the team."  What was the rebuke?

Comment: @JJChivers - Even that simple phrase change is going to be asking for opinions.  Perhaps a change to "When  and how is it acceptable to correct an employee in front of a client/customer?"

Comment: @xpy it would not matter if it was the boss asking the same question.  How could i have handled this better? is an acceptable question.  But we would need more details on how the situation was handled.  Or My manager found out I did this and chastized me for it and I do not understand why.  That is an acceptable question.  Right or wrong judgements are the problem.  There is no right answer.

Comment: As a customer, if I complained about an employee, I would be _shocked_ if that employee was told off by his boss right in front of me. It's totally unprofessional. The boss would drop in my esteem far below zero. I would also consider that if that is how little the boss cares for his employees, he probably cares even less for me.

Answer (score 7):

Like Myles said, generally praise is better in public while confronting is better in private.  The only time confrontation might be done in public is if there's not a chance to do so privately in a timely manner (the sooner it is done following the observed undesirable behavior, the better).

Given the little bit of your story, it seems likely the manager could have (and if so, should have) at least waited until after the meeting with the client was over.  But there may be more to the story we are unaware of.

What I do know is I've been on the client end as a customer in such a situation before - watching a manager reprimand his employee in front of me while they were trying to help me.  It is VERY uncomfortable.  I would think as a manager, doing such things is better in private anyway, for the sake of not making the client feel uncomfortable which could have the effect of losing that client.